# Why the provision's expire date not the same with the certificate's expire date

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a development certificate will be expired at  2022-07-14
[image]

And I create a provision with this certificate , but the provision 's expire date will be 2022-10-20
[image]

Why the provision and certificate's expire date are not the same date? Can the provision still effective after the certificate expire?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question for few months, I tried the below solution so you can try it.

If your profile expires then Simply generate the new provisioning profile.

Create build a new version with the new provisioning profile, and just make sure all your users/testers update to the new version of the app.

The easiest thing to do is to go into [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/), choose the expiring provisioning profile.

- Choose EDIT
- And Generate.

It will create a new one, you can also create automatic generating in Xcode general. Make sure you need to refresh Xcode's stash of provisioning profiles before creating a new build.